# Question: Kruskal-Wallis test for two groups

Tags: r, statistics, kruskal-wallis

I used a clustering tool to partition samples into two groups. Next, I want to see the statistical differences between them in terms of clinical features: Lymph nodes (continuous variables) and tumor stages (categorical variables)

Now, I used Kruskal Wallis test for the two clinical features above instead of Wilcoson sum rank test for Lymph node and Pearson's Chi-square for tumor stage. Is it accepted theoretically?

Comment: Hi Huy. As you may know, this website focuses on *specific* **programing** questions. It seems your question centers more on selection and interpretation of statistical analysis. Therefore, your question is likely more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: When you post your question on CrossValidated you need to make it clear that you are not testing for differences using any of the variables that you used in the cluster analysis.

Comment: #IanCampbell Sorry, it is my fault. Please close this topic :D I try closing it but I can't
#dcarlson Thanks for your suggestion